# Will three bulbs connected in parallel glow brighter than two bulbs in parallel?

Tags: electric-circuits

The question is simple but i have not heard anything like this before. This was asked by my teacher in the viva of my electrical workshop class. And she said the three bulbs will glow brighter and i had to tell the reason for this. Now was this a trick question or is this true? Cause i clearly said ma'am there will be no difference. I want to know the truth before the finals please help. Cause i cannot find a reason for the bulbs to glow brighter the voltage is same and the current will be divided among three bulbs now so why would they glow brighter?

Comment: Perhaps she meant that the three bulbs *in total* would glow brighter, which is true. But each individual bulb won't glow brighter.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to tell who's right: build the circuit and see what happens. Nature doesn't care about people's opinions, and She, by definition, will give you the right answer!

But you are correct: full marks on this one! If the three bulbs are connected in parallel across a voltage source, the voltage across them theoretically stays the same as when one bulb is connected across the same source.

The difference between the two situations is that, in the three bulb case, the total current drawn from the voltage source is tripled. This is what I think your teacher may be thinking of.

*Practically*, you will find that the bulbs will be slightly *dimmer* in the three bulb case as opposed to the one bulb case. This is because all practical voltage sources have a nonzero [*source impedance* (also called "internal impedance" or "output impedance")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_impedance), which means that they look like a voltage source in series with a resistance (in a DC circuit case). So, as the current increases to cope with the three bulb case, the voltage drop across the source impedance roughly triples, leading to a lower voltage across the parallel light bulbs.

Comment: Can you please tell more about impedance ? Cause if the answer is relating to impedance , then we shouldn't be asked about it since we have not studied impedance yet . Is impedance not only in AC ? By the way we were using AC.

Comment: @FawadHassanZaidi The main answer is not related to impedance. I'm just talking about practical effects: the three bulbs will dim slightly owing to source impedance. Source impedance is a DC concept too - you can think of it as source resistance and my comments still apply.  I emphasize again that your understanding for this problem as it stands (without impedance) is perfect: any number of bulbs connected across a perfect ideal voltage source must all have the same voltage across them, and a bulb's brightness depends only on the voltage across it (its resistance defines its current).